# chrome.tabs.executeScript not working on amazon.com

Tags: google-chrome-extension

the callback function never get called on amazon product pages, eg:
[https://www.amazon.com/AmazonBasics-0188-3-PACK-Multipurpose-Scissors/dp/B01BRGU8R0/ref=sr_1_13?dchild=1&keywords=amazonbasics&pf_rd_p=9349ffb9-3aaa-476f-8532-6a4a5c3da3e7&pf_rd_r=14VHDM69CE2KAX6H70ED&qid=1596591703&sr=8-13](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01BRGU8R0)

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId,
        {
            code: script,
            allFrames: true,
        },
        function (result) {
            console.log('run script result:', result);
            sendReplyToQuicker(true, "", result, msg.serial);
        })
```

as simple as only one line code will not getting result:

```js
1;
```

When run this code on other site:

[image: background page log on other site]

When run this code on amazon page, callback function nerver called:

[image: When run this code on amazon page]

The extension manifest.json ([full code](https://github.com/cuiliang/QuickerChromeConnector/blob/master/src/manifest.json)):

```
{
  "name": "Quicker Chrome Connector",
  "version": "0.3.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Native message connector with Quicker application",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "main.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "jquery-3.5.1.min.js",
        "content.js"
      ],
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon-128.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "nativeMessaging",
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>",
    "debugger"
  ],
  "optional_permissions":[
    "bookmarks",
    "browsingData",
    "topSites",    
    "downloads",
    "history",
    "pageCapture",
    "cookies",
    "sessions",
    "management"
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
  "homepage_url": "https://getquicker.net"
}
```

Comment: 1) Do you have amazon or a broader URL pattern in manifest.json's `permissions`? 2) Open `chrome://policy` and see if amazon is in `runtime_blocked_hosts`. 3) The page may still be loading for whatever reason so try adding `runAt: 'document_start'` to executeScript options.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you, 1) I have added manifest code in the question.  2) checked `chrome://policy` does not find `runtime_blocked_hosts` data. 3) I manually run code after document loaded (pass code from NativeHost). Other site can run code without problem. It's really strange.

Comment: What about runtime_allowed_hosts? Is there any extension-related policy? Also, try document_start anyway.

Comment: I affirm that amazon has some kind of protecion against this type of script injections. A script run with `executeScript` command is simply ignored.